# Beginner writing C code to program a round of yahtzee, function to hold dice values?

Tags: c

I'm at the very beginning of learning C code, and I'm having some issues with my homework. I need to have a function to hold dice values. I've written code for it, but once I try to put it into a function(keepArray) it doesn't seem to work for me. Here's what I have so far. Without a function, it seems to work. When I do put it into a function, no values are held.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
  const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 4;

  int diceArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];
  int keepArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];

  int i = 0;

  for (i = 0; i <= NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
    diceArray[i] = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    printf("%d ", diceArray[i]);
  }
  printf("\n");

  for (i = 0; i <= NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
    scanf("%d", &keepArray[i]);
    if (keepArray[i] == 1) {
      keepArray[i] = diceArray[i];
    }
    if (keepArray[i] == 0) {
      keepArray[i] = (rand() % 6) + 1;
    }
  }

  for (i = 0; i <= NUM_ELEMENTS; i++) {
    diceArray[i] = keepArray[i];

    printf("%d ", diceArray[i]);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

So I deleted my functions out of frustration, but I didn't get very far in the first place. Here's a try at what my functions might look like. It is mostly a copy paste of the above code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


  const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 5;



  int diceArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];



  int keepArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];


  int i = 0;

void

Roll(){
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)


    {



      diceArray[i] = (rand () % 6) + 1;



      printf ("%d ", diceArray[i]);

}

    }



Reroll(){


for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)

    {

      scanf ("%d", &keepArray[i]);
      if (keepArray[i] == 1)
    {
      keepArray[i] = diceArray[i];
    }
      if (keepArray[i] == 0)
    {
      keepArray[i] = (rand () % 6) + 1;
    }
    }
  for (i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
      diceArray[i] = keepArray[i];

      printf ("%d ", diceArray[i]);

}
    }
    int main(void)
    {
        Roll();
        Reroll();
}
```

I did mess around with my functions previously and got some sort of output, but I think it was still predicated on incorrect code. For the code now, I get and error
"main.c:9:7: error: variably modified ‘diceArray’ at file scope
   int diceArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];
       ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:13:7: error: variably modified ‘keepArray’ at file scope
   int keepArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];
       ^~~~~~~~~
main.c:40:1: warning: return type defaults to ‘int’ [-Wimplicit-int]
 Reroll(){
 ^~~~~~"

Comment: Aren't there **five** dice in yahtzee? Your loop control `i <= NUM_ELEMENTS` will break the 4-length array. You need `const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 5;` and loop to `i < NUM_ELEMENTS`. An array of length `4` can only be indexed by `0` to `3`.

Comment: This part of the code works. I think because elements start at 0, so it goes 0,1,2,3,4, for a total of five elements. I have no issues with the code I have right now, I just need to translate it to a function that does the same thing, and am having trouble with that part.

Comment: It is broken. You *cannot* store 5 dice values in an array of length 4, even if it "appears" to "work" at the moment. And the idiomatic loop which indexes `N` things will run from `0` to `N-1`, that is `< N` (and not `<= N-1`).

Comment: *"When I do put it into a function, no values are held"* - where is this function that doesn't work? Showing us code that does work (barring the UB mentioned earlier) and asking why code that you don't show doesn't work makes it hard to help you

Comment: Okay, so I'm definitely changing that bit :) would still appreciate a little help with the function

Comment: Pass the array where you want to store the dice values to the function you will write, which will perhaps be `void gethrow(int dice[NUM_ELEMENTS])`.

Answer (score 1):

`const int NUM_ELEMENTS = 5;` cannot be used for statically sized arrays in C.
When using it as array size it attempts to create "Variable Length Arrays" instead (which are not allowed in file scope, as the error is telling you).
You can fix this issue by making it a "true" constant, e.g.:

```
  #define NUM_ELEMENTS 5;
  int diceArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];
  int keepArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];
```

Or alternatively

```
  enum  { NUM_ELEMENTS = 5 };
  int diceArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];
  int keepArray[NUM_ELEMENTS];
```

Also you forgot to add a return type for your `Reroll` function, it should be `void Reroll(void)`

Comment: Thanks so much guys!! It's outputting now and I can finally move on!